# Intel vPro on AWS EC2 T2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, vpro

I have purchased an SSL certificate to use for a site running on an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance. I have to specify whether my certificate is for Intel vPro or not.

I can't seem to find a definitive answer in the AWS documentation on whether T2 instances use Intel vPro technology. Do they?

Comment: Why does your SSL certificate require you to specify vPro or not? Usually this is not a requirement.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? HTTPS for your website?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to buy a Code Signing Certificate. That is not what you need if you simply want to make your website available via HTTPS. What you need is a Server certificate. By the way, Amazon provides that for free if you put your website through CloudFront.